# Can't exhaust the load more button to unveil all the headlines

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've tried to keep clicking on ***`more`*** button located at the bottom of a webpage (in it's landing page) to unveil all the headlines. The thing is when I execute my script, It only click once and then stop. How can I keep clicking on that button until there is no more option to click?

***[Link to that website](https://www.newsnow.co.uk/h/Sport/Football/Championship/Transfer+News)***

This is my script so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

link = "https://www.newsnow.co.uk/h/Sport/Football/Championship/Transfer+News"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get(link)

while True:
    try:
        loadmore = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class^='hl_more']")))
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",loadmore)
        loadmore.click()
    except Exception: break
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code to simulate required behavior:

```
header = driver.find_element_by_id("phead")
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].style.position = "absolute";', header)
while True:
    try:    
        loadmore = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.hl_more.bg_tween:not(.nfloading)")))
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",loadmore)
        loadmore.click()
    except: break
```

Comment: Awesomely nice sir!!! I find it a little difficult to understand the logic your suggested script follows. It would be very good If you make me understand how it worked (in this comment section). Btw, the is one of your finest scripts I've got so far. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @asmitu , I made a little hack: the navigation panel has style `position="fixed"` that means that it always remains on the same place even if you scrolled the page. So when you're scrolling to button and trying to click it - navigation panel intercepts the click. Setting style `position = "absolute"` make it be *fixed* to page top

Comment: Much obliged sir. Thanks again.